# Please just check the problem. The function sortForm empty() does not effect on referenced id

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to finish my dictionary app. Before this morning everything was good with the app but I Want to check it today. And I realized that somethings going wrong because just a dumb function.
Here's the part of the code that I am still struggling.

**HTML**

```
<table id="records" border="1">
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
```

**JS**

```
function sortForm() {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'main/data.php',
      data:$("#sort").serialize(),
      dataType:"html",
      success: function(res) {
        $("#tbody").empty();
        $("#tbody").append(res);
      }
    });
  }
```

So let me clean the things. I want to make `tbody` empty and append the result. I have tried the others like `.html('');` and `.val('');` and `.innerHTML = '';`.
Btw the `tbody` is already contains some contents. I'm just trying to remove them.

So can I have the suggestions...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.html('')` seems to be working fine for me. Maybe your ajax request is not returning successfully and hence the function in success is not getting executed. Here's a jsfiddle link showcasing the same.

https://jsfiddle.net/2d16gc90/1/

Comment: I think so. I'll check the ajax. Thanks dude.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved the issue :)

Comment: Oh dude it is still same. I think it is something detail.